# Find duplicate words

Tags: c++

My code crashing when I try to do double while loop. This my homework, so I can't use any algorithm or `string`. Only char arrays allowed.
Can someone help me do fix it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char sepTxt[] = ".,:;()!%^?<>- ";
    int szTxt;
    char *txt = new char[256];
    cout << "Enter text length: ";
    cin >> szTxt;
    while(cin.fail())
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "\nFail. Try again.\nEnter text length: ";
        cin >> szTxt;
    }
    cin.ignore(1,'\n');
    cout << "Enter text: ";
    cin.getline(txt,szTxt);
    while (cin.fail() || strlen(txt) < 1)
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "\nFail. Try again.\nEnter text: ";
        cin.getline(txt,szTxt);
    }
    char *txtTmp = new char [szTxt]; //initialization dynamic arr for temp copy of entered text
    strncpy(txtTmp, txt, szTxt); //copy entered text to txtTmp
    char *bufTxt = strtok(txt, sepTxt); //find first word;
    char resTxt[256] = {};
    while (bufTxt) //crash here;
    {
        bufTxt = strtok(NULL, sepTxt);
        while ((txtTmp = strstr(txtTmp, bufTxt)))
        {
            strcat(resTxt,bufTxt);
            strcat(resTxt," ");
            txtTmp+=strlen(bufTxt);
        }
    }
    cout << "\nDouble words: " << resTxt;
    delete []txt, txtTmp;
}
```

Comment: you do second  strtok and don't check if it is NULL.

Comment: It's also crashing even if I check for NULL or add 
bufTxt = strtok(NULL, sepTxt);
in the end.

Comment: Recommendation: move `char *txt = new char[256];` to after you know the size of the text and change it to `char *txt = new char[szTxt];`. Fewer nasty surprises. Probably should add 1 for good measure. Odds are the user won't include the null terminator in the count.

Comment: Unrelated `delete[] txt, txtTmp;` will not delete both. Comma performs the the left side, discards the result and perform the right side and use the result. So this more or less breaks down in to `delete[] txt; txtTmp;` Nothing useful happens with `txtTmp`.

Comment: Unrelated: Your rubber duck wants to know why you get the next `bufTxt` before looking at the current one.

Comment: This needed because i need only next repeated words.
For example, if I have a string: test qwer test zzz test. I should get in the answer: test test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to simplify the code, for example allocating a local variable `char *txt = new char[256];` and then deleting it is useless, because `256` is a constant. `char txt[256];` is better in this case.

You ask the user how long the text is, but you are basically ignoring that size. Just assume `256` is enough. If text length is more than 256 then you cannot use `txt`, rather you have to allocate dynamically based on that size.

You can proceed to use `strtok`, no additional work is required.

```
const char sepTxt[] = ".,:;()!%^?<>- ";
char txt[256];
cin.getline(txt, sizeof(txt));

char *previous = nullptr;
char *token = strtok(txt, sepTxt);
while(token)
{
    token = strtok(nullptr, sepTxt);
    if(previous && token && strcmp(previous, token) == 0)
        cout << "duplicate " << token << endl;
    previous = token;
}
```

If duplicates don't appear next to each other then you have to read the words in to array. If `txt` is 256 bytes long, then it's safe to assume there won't be more than 256 words, you can declare `char *arr[256]` and assign each element to token value. Example:

```
char *arr[256] = { NULL };
int count = 0;
while(token)
{
    arr[count++] = token;
    token = strtok(nullptr, sepTxt);
    previous = token;
}

for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    for(int j = i + 1; j < count; j++)
    {
        if(strcmp(arr[i], arr[j]) == 0)
        {
            cout << "duplicate " << arr[i] << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tnx for help <3
But I need to get all the repeated words.
For example, if I have a string: test qwer test zzz test
I should get in the answer: test test
Only repeated occurrences of the word.
The code above works correctly only if there are repeated words on the left and right.

Comment: TNX YOU SOO MUCH <3